# display images randomly in 3 UIButton using single array content

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created three UIButton and i have 11 images in an array.  I want to display that images randomly in each and every buttons.

**Edited**

button2Image, button3Image, button4Image is NSString,

```
button2Image = [topButtonArray objectAtIndex:l1Counter];

NSArray *reversed = [[testArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
button3Image = [topButtonArray objectAtIndex:nextCounter+1];

int random = arc4random_uniform([topButtonArray count]);
button4Image = [topButtonArray objectAtIndex:random];
```

Note: I don’t want to display same image in each button.

Comment: Ok. What happened? What is the problem?

Comment: Your question is not clear for me. Where do you want to display that images? Please give us your code that you have already done.

Comment: i tried but two button display same image

Comment: Assuming you can set images to the button, you just need to implement random number generation function. Use "index = arc4random()%11";" to get the index of the random UIImage(considering images to UIImage) and set them as UIButton Images.

Comment: And since they are random, you can get both images to be same too.

Comment: Search for "non-repeating random numbers" ...

Comment: to stop repetition of images copy original array in temporary array and remove used image from the temporary array

Comment: By the way, If you have tried, please do show your code, for better understanding.

Comment: try my answer and let me know. This will give you random index of array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray *urImageArray;//11 images


NSMutableArray *threeImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

while ([threeImages count]<3) {

    id image=[urImageArray objectAtIndex:[self getRandomNumberBetween:0 maxNumber:11-1]];

    // Three images must be different
    if (![threeImages containsObject:image]) {

        [threeImages addObject:image];

    }




}


firstButtonImage = [threeImages objectAtIndex:0];

twoButtonImage = [threeImages objectAtIndex:1];

thirdButtonImage = [threeImages objectAtIndex:2];






- (NSInteger)getRandomNumberBetween:(NSInteger)min maxNumber:(NSInteger)max
{
    return min + arc4random() % (max - min + 1);
}
```

Comment: here i want two buttons random i.e., twoButtonImage and thirdButtonImage want to display random and firstButtonImage is ordered array

Comment: then only get 2 images for twoButtonImage & thirdButtonImage. change the while loop count and objectAtIndex as o,1

Comment: if you follow up my code then you would not get the repeated image

Comment: firstButtonImage is an ordered array and twoButtonImage and thirdButtonImage is random.  Problem is firstButtonImage and twoButtonImage or thirdButtonImage is display same image because of that ordered array.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is how to pick random elements from array, here is a nice article with examples: http://nshipster.com/random/.
For example:

```
NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//i is number of required random elements
int i = 3;
while (i-->0)
{
    if ([array count] > 0) {
        int idx = arc4random_uniform([array count]);
        [resultArray addObject:array[idx]];
        //array is a mutable array whether the original one or it's deep copy
        [array removeObjectAtIndex:idx];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post "link-only" answers. Always provide the relevant information in the answer itself.

Answer (score 1):

For that you have to non-repeating random number. Then use that number to get the image from image array

```
arr123=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        int random = arc4random_uniform(11);
        [arr123 addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",random]];
        [self do1];

        NSLog(@"%@",arr123);


int iMatch=0;
-(void)do1
{
    int random =  arc4random_uniform(11);

    if([arr123 count]==2)
        return;

    for(int i=0;i<1;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<[arr123 count];j++)
        {
            if(random==[[arr123 objectAtIndex:j] intValue])
            {
                iMatch=1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(iMatch==1)
        {
            iMatch=0;
            [self do1];
        }
        else
        {
            iMatch=0;
            [arr123 addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",random]];
             [self do1];
        }
    }
}
```

Then use the arr123 array to get the random images from image array using the random indexes

Comment: i tried i got same number at rare time e.g.,(0,9,9) like this

Comment: perfect.  But i want here two buttons random and first button is ordered array.

Comment: What is mean by ordered array??

Comment: that is not random.  It will display order list(0, 11) i.e., 1st image, 2nd, 3rd, and so on.But that's not a prob.  Here i want two instead of three in your code.

Comment: Updated the answer dude. It was too easy just to change the for loop and one if condition

Comment: Please accept answer if u find fruitful to you so that other also use it

Answer (score 0):

you should create an NSSet with the objects you get from the array. The NSSet has only distinct objects so you will add random objects from the array to the NSSet until the NSSet counts 3 objects. Look at apple NSSet documentation: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html